# How do I transfer numbers/contacts from Windows Mobile to Android?

Tags: contacts, data-transfer, windows-mobile

I finally activated my Android phone and would like to import numbers/contacts to the new phone. I forgot to ask the store rep how to do this, but I figured since both of them can be hooked up to a computer, I can probably do it myself. I'm on a Windows platform.

What's the best way to do this?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It's pretty easy because your Android phone will sync to [Google Contacts][1].

1. Sync your Windows Mobile phone to your computer (Outlook, Outlook Express, whatever you normally sync to)
2. Export your contacts from there to a CSV:

   1. Go to the File menu on the top-left in the Outlook
   2. Click on Import and Export
   3. Click on Export file to
   4. Click Next
   5. Click on Comma Separated Values (Windows)
   6. Click on Next
   7. click on Contacts
   8. Click on Browse
   9. Select the drive and folder where you want to save the file
   10. Click on Next, and done
3. Use Google Contacts to import the CSV (import is in the upper right from https://contacts.google.com/)
4. Wait a couple of minutes.  All of your contacts will show up on your Android phone soon

Comment: That's how I moved and merged my contacts from a combination of an old Nokia phone (exported to CSV using Nokia's rubbishy desktop software), and an Outlook account, and imported them both into GMail's contacts. It even gives you an option to merge two contacts in GMail if you tick them both at the same time.

Comment: Thanks, this worked perfectly.  My old Windows Mobile phone already synced my contacts with Outlook so I just needed to export/import.

Comment: In my case, I needed to manually open CSV-file in spreadsheet programm and rename columns. Before I did so contacts wasn't imported correctly to Google account. Maybe this happened due to regional differences. Also different programs use different delimiters for CSV.

Answer (score 7):

An even simpler method (at least for me) would be to first sync your contacts in WinMo to Google Sync. The Active sync settings are:

- Server: m.google.com
- Use SSL
- Username and password are the same as other Google services (username@gmail.com-format)
- Contacts must be selected in the data selection

And then on your Android phone, you should have automatic contact sync enabled by default.

Did this with my HTC Touch HD and Motorola Milestone/Droid, took a couple of minutes, and everything on the Android side went completely automagically.

Comment: Looks like this does not work anymore - https://support.google.com/a/users/answer/138636 ("Starting Jan. 30, 2013, only Google Apps for Work, Education, and Government customers can set up new devices with Google Sync")

Answer (score 1):

I just transferred my contacts from my HTC Touch Pro2 to my Samsung Galaxy S II X.

You need to install the Bluetooth File Transfer app for Android, pair your two phones, and then send your contacts to your Android phone using the Windows Mobile Bluetooth Explorer program.

Answer (score 0):

You could also try [vCardIO](http://code.google.com/p/vcardio/) which uses the Funambol code and runs on an Android phone off the SD card. Export from Outlook and copy the file to the SD card.

Answer (score 0):

**Disclaimer: I do not work for Sprite Software**

I did a search for the following phrase on Google: "moving windows mobile contacts to android". One of the hits was Sprite Software who makes the following application: SpriteMigrate. It's free and purports to backup your stuff to a backup file and then you use a second program on your PC to convert that backup file to Android-ready format.

Sprite Migrate apparently saves the following information (from their website):

> What do we migrate?
>
> - Contacts
> - Call Logs
> - SMS
> - Bookmarks
>
> much more coming soon...

I've performed step 1 already and am in the process of performing step 2, once I pick up my phone tomorrow (Evo), I'll try step 3 and report back on how successful I was.

Answer (score 0):

I tried [LocalSync](http://www.psencik.cz/local-sync) and it worked fine.

Pros:

- It doesn't simply "migrate" WinMo to Android: it actually establishes a sync relationship with your Windows PC/Outlook
- Doesn't share contacts with Google or other clouds (privacy safe)

Cons:

- You must have Outlook installed on Windows

Answer (score 0):

Use the following simple steps (no need for Microsoft/Google account)

1. Search/install [contacts+message backup](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/contacts-message-backup/9nblgggz57gm?activetab=pivot:overviewtab) on your Windows Phone
2. Go to Settings -> contacts+message backup -> Backup from the list that is displayed, select Contacts, and then press Backup. A folder named "backup + restore" will be created in your SD card/phone memory containing the vCard file.
3. Copy this file to your Android device and import contacts from this file

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to the account settings.
2. Choose Microsoft exchange.
3. Log in to sync.
4. Note that Microsoft Outlook online calendar, mail, contacts are synced. No need to create a Google account.

Don't know if it matters but this was on Android7.

Answer (score -2):

You can use [Qontact](http://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/store/app/qontact/e3404be4-324f-46e3-b47d-5561c676cad6) (I'm the developer of this app). It can export in many formats like vCard, readable by iOS or Android app. Just send the contacts by email and open the attachment (Gmail or Hotmail account).

The free version can export about 200 contacts (including photo, the solutions that use CVS exports doesn't). In case you have more contacts, you can use the [pro version](http://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/store/app/qontact-pro/047163c0-04cb-4d28-aec3-01115c3769b3).