# Windows Phone To Android

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, 5.0-lollipop, windows, file-transfer, data-transfer

I am looking to move my windows phone's call history, messages and contacts to an Android phone. I can root the android hone if needed. The windows phone is running 8.1. I have looked in to this and I can only seem to find how to move my pictures and my contacts. Is this even a possible swap? If not can I call Microsoft and ask them to do something?

Don't know if this is the right forum but thanks!

Comment: What Android phone are you planning on moving it to?

Comment: droid maxx is my phone I got now.

Comment: Related: [How do I transfer numbers/contacts from Windows Mobile to Android?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/11417) / [Moving contacts and messages from Windows Phone 8.1 to Android](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/115599) / [Switching contacts from Windows Phone to Android](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/86105) /  [Contact migration from Windows Phone 7.8 to Android 5.0 Lollipop](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/96974) / and maybe more.

Comment: for contacts: https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/16450/how-to-transfer-contacts-to-android/16498#16498